# Cannot fit inner image into its parent container on this ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have one very basic `ReactJS` component called: `Designer` which displays the `Eiffel Tower` as well as a bottom panel with some controls in it.

The `Designer` is inside a `div` with the following size: `{ width: 510px, height: 300px}`.

The `Eiffel Tower` image has the following size: `{ width: 300px, height: 800px}`.

This is the current rendered output of the `Designer`:

[image]

But my problem is that the `Eiffel Tower` image is not getting fit into its parent `div`.

> My goal is what you can see on the following image:

[image]

If on the file: `/src/CanvasCrop/CanvasCrop` we do: `let showImage = false;`, we get the following:

[image]

so, we confirm that its parent `div` (`green` background) gets sized accordingly having its own `width` and `height` whether the image is getting shown or not.

Here is its source code (original):

`/src/CanvasCrop/CanvasCrop`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./CanvasCrop.scss";

class CanvasCrop extends Component {
  render() {
    let showImage = true;
    return (
      <div className="partial-designer-canvas-crop">
        <div>
          {
          showImage &&
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/DKxRFtb/image.jpg"
            style={{
              maxWidth: "100%",
              maxHeight: "100%",
              transform: "scale(-50%, -50%)"
            }}
            alt="target"
          />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CanvasCrop;
```

Here is the outer source code:

`/index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.scss";
import Designer from "./Designer/Designer";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span class="title">Trying to fit Eiffel Tower</span>
      <div className="App"
      style={{
        // keep this as it is
        overflow: 'auto', 
        width: '510px',
        height: '300px',
      }}
    >
      <Designer />
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here you have the `CodeSandbox.io` you can experiment with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/7jv56qr1yx

Could you please, **provide back a fork** of the above `CodeSandbox.io` with the `Eiffel Tower` fitted into its parent `div` without setting manually a fixed `width / height`?

**Side note:** if instead of a `portrait` image, we use a `landscape` image, it should also fit into its parent `div` without going beyond its limits.

Example image (size: `{ width: 800px, height: 300px}`):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUeCD.jpg

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it looks like you are missing a `height: 100%` on your `.partial-designer-canvas`.

Here, try this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/x664y69ow

I only changed `src/Canvas/Canvas.scss`.  You can add a calc to account for your tool bar too, like so:

`.partial-designer-canvas {height: calc(100% - 60px)}`